# How to make blogger post to redirect to another domain with same post url

Tags: post, dns, blogger

Please I want to know how to redirect my blogger post from my old domain to my new domain name pointing each post to their respective post

Comment: Were you using a custom domain on the old blog or was it a blogspot.com type URL?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings** > **Search preferences** > **Custom Redirects** and make a new redirect.

URL must start with `/` like this `/2017/12/living-can-bring-does-comments-letter.html`

Answer (score 0):

On the old domain's Blogger template, add the following Javascript snippet in the `<head>` region -

```
<script>
  window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(window.location.origin,"http://www.newdomain.com") 
</script>
```

Replace `http://www.newdomain.com` with your new domain